# Retaining value when reloading page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, path, reload

I have a situation with changing user's CSS theme on site like following:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#switch', function (e) {
                var isChecked = $('input', this).is(':checked');
                $("input", this).attr('checked', isChecked);

                $.post("/User/SwitchTheme", { userid: $('.cekirajMe').val(), type: isChecked==true? 1 : 0 })
                    .done(function (data) {
                        if (data == "ok") {
                            location.reload(true);
                        }
                 });
            });
```

The  code that triggers post to switch theme method is located in a shared layout cshtml file...

Let's say that I'm on following path:

```
 Controller/Action1
```

And the switch theme was triggered from  that path (since the code is located in shared layout cs html page), and I changed my theme from white to dark

Now if I go back in my browser by pressing previous page button, I will still have the white theme to load instead of dark...

Does anyone knows whats causing this issue?

Comment: The previous page is loaded from the browser's cache. That includes the stylesheets in the previous page.

Comment: @Cerbrus Okay but is there any way for me to clear that cache ... ? Codewise, any tips on how to load dark even when he presses previous page?

Comment: Depends on how you switch the themes. You could disable caching on the stylesheets' headers, but you generally don't want to do that...

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand, is there any way to do it programatically just for this action when performed/

Comment: @User987 add css class to your body `dark-theme` and `light-theme` depending on what theme are chosen, and write your css properties something like `dark-theme a { color: 'black' }`, `light-theme a { color: 'white' }`